# how can I decrypt the content in frontend which was encrypted in backend

Tags: reactjs, node.js, cryptojs, aes-gcm, webcrypto-api

It might be a little problem but I'm neither getting any specific error nor getting any solution.
I am building a full stack project. In here I need a condition where I have to encrypt a content in backend part of the project. I'm using symmetric key cryptography and using `aes_256_gcm` in crypto-js. this is the code of backend part.

```
import { randomBytes, createCipheriv } from "crypto";

const encryptMessage = (message, credential) => {
  const key = Buffer.from(credential, "utf-8");
  const iv = randomBytes(16);
  const cipher = createCipheriv("aes-256-gcm", key, iv);
  const encryptedMessage = Buffer.concat([
    cipher.update(message, "utf-8"),
    cipher.final(),
  ]);
  const tag = cipher.getAuthTag();

  return {
    iv: iv.toString("hex"),
    encryptedMessage: encryptedMessage.toString("hex"),
    tag: tag.toString("hex"),
  };
};


export default encryptMessage;
```

now I am storing this content in a variable in backend and then passing it to frontend.

now I am trying to decrypt this message in frontend using same `iv`, `tag`, and `credential` in the code. this is the code of decryption in frontend.

```
const decryptMessage = async (encryptedData, credential) => {
  
  const decoder = new TextDecoder();
  
  const iv = new Uint8Array(encryptedData.iv.match(/.{1,2}/g).map((byte) => parseInt(byte, 16)));
  const encryptedMessage = new Uint8Array(encryptedData.encryptedMessage.match(/.{1,2}/g).map((byte) => parseInt(byte, 16)));
  const tag = new Uint8Array(encryptedData.tag.match(/.{1,2}/g).map((byte) => parseInt(byte, 16)));

  const encodedCredential =new TextEncoder().encode(credential)

  try{
  const key = await crypto.subtle.importKey(
    "raw",
    encodedCredential,
    { name: "AES-GCM" },
    false,
    ["decrypt"]
  );

  const decrypted = await crypto.subtle.decrypt(
    { name: "AES-GCM", 
    iv: iv,
    tag: tag },
    key,
    encryptedMessage
  );

    const decryptedMessage = decoder.decode(decrypted);

    console.log("Decrypted Message:", decryptedMessage);
    return decryptedMessage;

  }catch(error){
    console.error("Decryption Error:", error);
    throw new Error ("Decryption Failed" + error.message);
  }
}

export default decryptMessage
```

In here I am not getting any specific error. just getting `Decryption Error: Error`. When I applied `console.log()` I'm getting the output till before `decrypted` function.
And this is how I'm calling this function in another file.
`const privateKey = await decryptMessage(keys, credential);`

Anyone can please explain why is the error happening. And if it will never work, then how can do this. means to encrypt the content in backend and decrypt it in frontend.

Comment: Do you really need to do this at all? Content sent between frontend and backend should already be encrypted by TLS (assuming you're using HTTPS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value passed to `crypto.subtle.decrypt()` in the first parameter for `algorithm` is incorrect: `{ name: "AES-GCM", iv: iv, tag: tag }`. A property `tag` is not defined for [`AesGcmParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AesGcmParams) at all.
Instead, `crypto.subtle.decrypt()` expects the concatenation of ciphertext and tag to be passed for [`data`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/decrypt#data) in the third parameter in the case of GCM.

Fixed code (the input data was generated with your NodeJS code):

```js
(async () => {

const decryptMessage = async (encryptedData, credential) => {      
  const decoder = new TextDecoder();      
  const iv = new Uint8Array(encryptedData.iv.match(/.{1,2}/g).map((byte) => parseInt(byte, 16)));
  const encryptedMessage = new Uint8Array(encryptedData.encryptedMessage.match(/.{1,2}/g).map((byte) => parseInt(byte, 16)));
  const tag = new Uint8Array(encryptedData.tag.match(/.{1,2}/g).map((byte) => parseInt(byte, 16)));
  const encodedCredential =new TextEncoder().encode(credential)
  try{
    const key = await crypto.subtle.importKey(
      "raw",
      encodedCredential,
      { name: "AES-GCM" },
      false,
      ["decrypt"]
    );
    /*
    const decrypted = await crypto.subtle.decrypt(
      { name: "AES-GCM", 
      iv: iv,
      tag: tag },
      key,
      encryptedMessage
    );
    */
    const decrypted = await crypto.subtle.decrypt( 
      { name: "AES-GCM", 
      iv: iv }, // Fix: remove tag
      key,
      new Uint8Array([...encryptedMessage, ...tag]) // Fix: concatenate ciphertext and tag
    );
    const decryptedMessage = decoder.decode(decrypted);
    console.log("Decrypted Message:", decryptedMessage);
    return decryptedMessage;
  } catch(error){
    console.error("Decryption Error:", error);
    throw new Error ("Decryption Failed" + error.message);
  }
}
var encryptedData = {
  iv: 'd38d7f07a4511b9f3cc79acb66b42528',
  encryptedMessage: 'd3da8f3da785b05ad4c2d462672379c287ba7640b971a3360d783e35acd6c9d1580555a1cb2927f1678147',
  tag: '7146b3fd125b59e718c4cd8cb39f8142'
};
var credential = '01234567890123456789012345678901';
var ct = '123ce86e38eed47a1658d8df832ed59eac3ac5465f0865583c2e48dba32b170307fa12d18e9f46691acd2c';
var dt = await decryptMessage(encryptedData, credential);

})();
```

---

Security: Keep in mind that in case of a passphrase as key material it is more secure to use a key derivation function like Argon2 or at least PBKDF2 (in conjunction with a random salt).